# No errors with installing LetsEncrypt certificate on Windows Server 2012 R2, but HTTPS still isn't loading...?

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl, certificate

I've been trying to get the free LetsEncrypt SSL certificate to work with IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I went through the ACMESharp github tutorial ( `https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESHarp/wiki/Example-Usage` and `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVUY7ygbGm8` ) and got everything to work without errors on Powershell... There was one Powershell error before which I solved by simply exporting and re-importing the certificate in IIS.

However, despite now being error-free on Powershell (except for a few warnings https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbKWC.jpg (crossed out the hash and my username here) ), loading the HTTPS version of my site still doesn't actually work. If you try to, the connection just times out.

Please let me know if you have any ideas as to what's possibly going wrong. When I look at the Server Certificates in IIS, it looks good: Issued To (my domain), Issued By Let's Encrypt Authority X1, Expires May 2016, Certificate Hash (redacted), Certificate Store (personal)

The URL I used when signing up for LetsEncrypt was: `https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when I have an issue like this it's because the Service Account running the Application Pool that the Site is in has no access to read the private key for the certificate.  This might be something to look into.

Comment: That sounds really promising, but do you mind showing me how to check for that? I see "Application Pools" in IIS Manager but I'm not sure where to go to deal with private keys.

Comment: The private keys are stored in the file system.  Using the cert:\ provider in PowerShell you can get the exact container name, but I usually can look in the file system location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\ and see the file that was created when the certificate was imported.  You can then simply set the file permissions in NTFS.  Check the application pool in IIS to see what identity it is running with.

Comment: This is assuming that you already have an HTTPS binding setup for the site, that it's on port 443, that if you create an HTTP binding it isn't an issue, etc